# $X,Y$ are independent random variables with normal distributions $N(6,4)$ and $N(6,7)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables with normal distributions $N(6,4)$ and $N(6,7)$ respectively. Then:

$(A)$ Random variable $Z:=X+Y$ has density $f(x)=\frac{1}{22\sqrt\pi}e^{-\frac{(x-12)^2}{22}}$ ;

$(B)$ Random variable $Z:=X-Y$ may take negative values ;

$(C)$ Random variable $Z:=X-Y$ only takes negative values ;

I have to prove or disprove these.

---

$ad. (A)\;\;$ proper answer is $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi\sqrt{22}}e^{-\frac{(x-12)^2}{22}}$ so it's wrong ;

$ad. (B)$ and $(C)\;\;$ if $N(6,4)+N(6,7) = N(12,11)$, then is it right that $N(6,4)-N(6,7) = N(0,-3)$? I suppose that it's not, but then I have no idea how to make this one. Should I do anything with $P(Z\leq t)=P(X-Y \leq t)=...$ ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $N(6,4)-N(6,7) = N(0,11)$

Comment: $X=-X$ in distribution

Comment: $N(6,4)-N(6,7) = N(6,4)+N(-6,7) = N(0,11)$

Comment: So $E(Z)=0$ and $Var(Z)=11$. But I don't know yet how to find if it may take negative values. Does it mean that it takes only positive values?

Comment: formally speaking, any normal variable with non-zero variance can take negative values..

Comment: I'm concluding then, that $(b)$ is true, and $(c)$ is false?